# Paths of files on Google Nearline changed

Tags: path, cloudberry

While I was recovering files by CloudBerry, I realized that the paths of nearly all files on the Google Cloud are altered.

It should be

G:\2014\Photo Video Source Files\UTS construction video\GOPR2856 UTS Construction.MP4

but it is saved on Google Nearline like this

G:\2014\Photo Video Source Files\UTS construction video\GOPR2856 UTS Construction.MP4%3A\20130202191902\GOPR2856 UTS Construction.MP4

I do not know why the file name became folder name and move it down to numeric folder.

I thought it may be due to CloudBerry, but it did not happen on Amazon Glacier.

Does anybody know why this happened and how to fix? Is there any tool to fix the path and file/folder name locally? This is terrible situation, and we cannot work with it. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably doing [incremental backups](https://www.google.fi/amp/s/www.cloudberrylab.com/blog/incremental-backup-explained/amp/). The `\20130202191902\` suggests there might be several modified versions of the same file backed up. Such backups are ment to be recovered using the same tool that created them, not by copying the files back.